# SwiftUI - Color RGB - ignoresSafeArea()

Tags: xcode, swiftui, background-color

SwiftUI - Color RGB - ignoresSafeArea()

Hey guys, (sorry for my bad English)

i have a Problem.

```
import SwiftUI

// Willkommen Slider //

struct Content_View: View {
    @State private var pageIndex = 0
    private let pages: [Page] = Page.samplePages
    private let dotAppearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $pageIndex) {
            ForEach(pages) { page in
                ZStack{
                    Color(red: 36 / 255 , green: 36 / 255, blue: 36 / 255)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack{
                        Spacer()
                        PageView(page: page)
                        Spacer()
                        if page == pages.last{
                            Button("Sign UP", action: goToZero)
                                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                        } else {
                            Button("next", action: incrementPage)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                    .tag(page.tag)
                }
            }

            .animation(.easeInOut, value: pageIndex)
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .interactive))
            .onAppear{
                dotAppearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .blue
                dotAppearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = .gray
            }
        }
    
        func incrementPage() {
            pageIndex += 1

        }

        func goToZero(){
            pageIndex = 0
        }
    
    }
    
    // Willkommen Slider Ende //
    
    
    struct Content_View_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Content_View()
        }
    }
```

I have on the top and bottom, white color, but i have in the ZStack the modifier
.ignoresSafeArea() ?

What is the Problem of this code? I am a completely Newbie. :)

Thx Mates

I have tried
ignoresSafeArea(.top) (.all)
edgesIgnoringSafeArea (.all) (.top)

nothing helps

Comment: This is not a [mre] and it's unclear what the problem is